# Display textbox/button on selection of radio button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have two radio buttons.  On selection of one I want to display two text boxes and a button, and on selection of the other radio button, I want to display one textbox and a button. Please help me out with it as I'm new to Javascript.

Here's my code:

```js
   

 function ShowHideDiv() {
            var chkYes = document.getElementById("chkYes");
            var dvtext = document.getElementById("dvtext");
            dvtext.style.display = chkYes.checked ? "block" : "none";
        }
```

```css
             

  

 .lgntxt {
     font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
     font-size:12px;
     font-weight:400;
     height:20px;
     padding-left:20px;
     
    }
```

```html
   

   

              <label for="chkYes">
                <input type="radio" id="chkYes" name="chk" onclick="ShowHideDiv()" />
                I am new on Swadonline
            </label>
            <br>
            <label for="chkYes">
                <input type="radio" id="chkYes" name="chk" onclick="ShowHideDiv()" />
                I already have a Swadonline account
            </label>
            <br>
            <br>
            <div id="dvtext" style="display: none" class="lgntxt">
                Please enter your Email Address *
                <br>
                <input type="text" id="txtBox" />
            </div>
```

Comment: What happens when running that code?  Syntax, logic error, you do not see what you want (and what do you see), ...

Comment: I want one button and one textbox to display when I click on "I am new to Swadonline" and two texboxes and one button to display when I click on "I already have a Swadonline account"

Comment: Sorry you missunderstood I think, with the current code you posted in the question, what happens, since it is not what you expect / want?

Comment: With the current code, when I click on "I am new to Swadonline", it displays only one text box, without a button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
   

 function ShowHideDiv() {
            var chkYes1 = document.getElementById("chkYes1");
            var dvtext1 = document.getElementById("dvtext1");
var chkYes2 = document.getElementById("chkYes2");
            var dvtext2 = document.getElementById("dvtext2");
            var button = document.getElementById("button");
            dvtext1.style.display = chkYes1.checked||chkYes2.checked ? "block" : "none";

            dvtext2.style.display = chkYes2.checked ? "block" : "none";

button.style.display = chkYes1.checked || chkYes2.checked ? "block" : "none";
        }
```

```css
             

  

 .lgntxt {
     font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
     font-size:12px;
     font-weight:400;
     height:20px;
     padding-left:20px;
     
    }
```

```html
   

   

              <label for="chkYes1">
                <input type="radio" id="chkYes1" name="chk" onclick="ShowHideDiv()" checked />
                I am new on Swadonline
            </label>
            <br>
            <label for="chkYes2">
                <input type="radio" id="chkYes2" name="chk" onclick="ShowHideDiv()" />
                I already have a Swadonline account
            </label>
            <br>
            <br>
            <div id="dvtext1"  class="lgntxt">
                text box 1
                <br>
                <input type="text" id="txtBox" />
            </div>
            <div id="dvtext2" class="lgntxt" style="display: none">
                text box 2
                <br>
                <input type="text" id="txtBox" />
            </div>
            <button  id="button">button</button>
```

Comment: Thanks for reaching out padre, but the radio button doesn't seem to deselect when the other option is selected, the both of them remain selected

Comment: Made some changes. check now.

Comment: Thanks for reaching out compadre

Comment: In addition compadre, I want one radio button to be selected, whenever the page loads

Answer (score 0):

Id of the radio button should be the unique through out the page. And also use "onchange" event for radio button instead of onclick. Technically you can use onclick event though! you can see this [link](http://www.dyn-web.com/tutorials/forms/radio/onclick-onchange.php)